# Is magic (as in tricks and performances) allowed in Puzzling.SE?

Tags: discussion, scope, on-topic

I am curious as to whether there is a Magic SE community or whether this is the closest thing to it. I know that there was a Magic SE put forward in Area 51 but it was closed. If some are allowed, what sorts and in what kind of context?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no site in the network which currently accepts these question, as e.g. indicated in this Meta Stack Exchange question: [Candidate SE site for asking about AGT Magics tricks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/343936/295232). An Area 51 proposal would make sense but without an existing userbase (partially from elsewhere on the Internet) there is a very low chance that it's successful. After all, most professionals in this business don't want to explain anything but the most basic tricks.

Sometimes it's possible to reframe a card trick into a puzzle, by describing a sequence of actions by a magician and a volunteer, and asking how the magician is able to name the correct card every time. An example is the puzzle [Five Card Magic Trick with $N$ card Deck](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/20379/11110). You can browse the [magic](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic) tag to see what kind of magic questions are acceptable on this site.